# getting an error when trying to import a list into a mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

whenever i try to add a list into the mysql table I get an error : 'ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement'

ive tried to look online but all i could found is that i need to use %s to solve this and not any other type of placeholders but i alredy do..

my code (just mentioning that i have like 20 name in that list, but i dont think it really matters):

```
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user=d,passwd=z,database=y)
listname=['name1','name2','name3','name4']
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
mysqlcommand='INSERT INTO tabletest (firstname) values (%s)'
mycursor.executemany(mysqlcommand,listname)
```

thank you!

Comment: is the number of items in your list match the number of columns in the table? you should explicitly list out the columns you are inserting data in to

Comment: @aws_apprentice thanks for the quick response! i am trying to have a table with only one column, that is called firstname, the list contains all of the names to put, one by one , each name supposed to be in another row.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `executemany` must be a sequence of sequences or mappings, i.e.

```
listname=[('name1',), ('name2',), ('name3',), ('name4',)]
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html:

> This method prepares a database `operation` (query or command) and executes it against all parameter sequences or mappings found in the sequence `seq_of_params`.

Comment: thanks, that works.
the problem with this method, is that when i try to recive the table from another script, i get it the same way:
    sqlcommand='select * from testtable'
    mycursor.execute(sqlcommand)
    records.fetchall()

and then all seems like the list i imported

Comment: That has nothing to do with the way you insert the records. `.fetchall()` will return a sequence of sequences too.